# RDC sessions to Win 7 terminate on CTR and arrow keys

Tags: macos

I am trying to do a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) from my Powerbook G4 (OSX 10.5.8) to a Windows 7 machine. The connection is established without any issues and the remote destop is 
displayed properly. However, hitting CTR or one of the arrow keys terminates the RDC session which is very annoying as you can imagine.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com. My guess is that Ctrl+arrow normally triggers screen rotation in some kind of video driver utility, which will only work when the regular display is being used.

Comment: Mmm... happens separately on CTR key and on AROW keys, not on the combination. Thanks for the superuser.com tip

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by downgrading to RDC 1.0.3 (  http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/9/6/4963025f-1731-4a9e-a9e6-8f6ab6ac4625/RDC103EN.bin )